# Adding elements from previous iterations in for loop C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, addition

I'm relatively new to C++ so this question might seem dumb, that's why I'm here for. Doing Advent of Code 2019, day 1. I'd like the data that is being read from a .txt into `void data()` to be added up to itself and be printed sequentially, after each iteration. 
This is what I got so far:

```
void data() {
    int fuel = 0, forMass = 0, forEach[100], forAll = 0, lines;
    //int MassArr[];
    std::ifstream infile("./Day1Input.txt"); //reading from .txt
    std::string line;


    for (lines = 0; std::getline(infile, line); lines++) {

        fuel = std::stoi(line);
        std::cout << "Module number [" << lines+1 << "]'s Mass = " << fuel << "\n";
        forEach[lines] = fuel / 3 - 2;
        std::cout << "Fuel required = " << forEach[lines] << "\n\n";

        /* *****THIS IS THE TRICKY PART*****
        forMass = (lines>0) ? forEach[lines] =+ fuel / 3 - 2 : forEach[lines];
        std::cout << "Fuel required so far = " << forMass << "\n";

        forAll = forMass += forEach[lines];
        std::cout << "Fuel required for mass and fuel so far = " << forAll << "\n";
        */
    }
}
```

`forMass` and `forAll` don't incrementally add to themselves with each iteration. Again, I'm sorry if this is too obvious but any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Hard to know what you're doing wrong when I'm not sure what it's supposed to do at all.

Comment: Unrelated, but since you are learning get rid of the habit of using c-style arrays imidiately. `forEach` should be a `std::vector<int>` or `std::array<int, 100>`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to accumulate the values of each forEach inside the forMass variable, the following line has something wrong:

```
forMass = (lines>0) ? forEach[lines] =+ fuel / 3 - 2 : forEach[lines];
```

you can fix it like this:

```
forMass += forEach[lines];
```

you don't need to check lines>0 unless you want to count two times the value of forEach[lines] on the first iteration.

Moreover the expression:

```
forEach[lines] =+ fuel / 3 - 2
```

is not correct if you want to increment another time forEach[lines], in this case you need to use +=,the =+ you wrote is not an increment operator is just equivalent to (= (backspace) +) ie: is just an assignment with a plus sign (that do nothing in this context).